# How to concatenate these arrays per element when the number of arrays are formed from a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a bunch of arrays which will be formed from a loop. I know I can concatenate via this method but I can only get it to work for an already established number of arrays:

```
y1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
y2 = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
z = np.array([a+b for a, b in zip(y1, y2)])
```

but how do I get it to work if I have many more arrays i.e. if I have these arrays as input going up to array x:

```
y1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
y2 = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
.
.
.
yx = ['C22', 'C23', 'C24']
```

And I want to get an output:

```
z = ['C1C4...C22', 'C2C5...C23', 'C3C6...C24']
```

Comment: If you had the arrays stored against keys in a dictionary, rather than actual names like `y1`, `y2`, then it would be simple. This is a classic reason not to have variable number of variables.

Comment: `lsts = [y1, y2]; [''.join(t) for t in zip(*lsts)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all these arrays in another array the moment they are created and then `zip` the array that contains them as follows:

```
import numpy as np
y1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
y2 = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
y = [y1,y2]
z = np.array(["".join(elem) for elem in zip(*y)])
print(z)
```

This will give you:

```
['C1C4' 'C2C5' 'C3C6']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `numpy` for that task you might employ `numpy.apply_along_axis` function. Consider example:

```
import numpy as np
def joiner(x):
    return ''.join(x)
y1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
y2 = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
y = np.array([y1,y2])
z = np.apply_along_axis(joiner,0,y)
print(list(z)) #gives ['C1C4', 'C2C5', 'C3C6']
```

As noted above you would need some structure to store your `y1,y2,...` - in my solution `np.array` is used for that. If you want to know more about `numpy.apply_along_axis` read its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).